# Brother printer dpkg doesn't seem to work

Tags: drivers, printing, dpkg, brother

I have a Brother HL-2240 printer which I'm trying to make compatible with Ubuntu. I followed the instructions for installing their drivers here:
http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=hl2240_us_eu&redirect=on#dpkg3

I managed to get as far as checking the install of the dpkg: when I went "dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother" it said this:

ii cupswrapperHL2240 2.0.4-2
i386 Brother HL-2240 CUPS wrapper driver
ii printer-driver-ptouch 1.3-8
i386 printer driver Brother p-touch label
printers

So I've taken that to mean that everything is successfully installed (please correct me if I'm wrong).
However, when I try to print a document in Libreoffice, it only prints a blank page. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing Brother printer drivers as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install brother-lpr-drivers-ac brother-lpr-drivers-bh7 brother-lpr-drivers-common brother-lpr-drivers-extra brother-lpr-drivers-laser brother-lpr-drivers-laser1
```

Comment: So I just copy and paste that whole line into the terminal?

Comment: Ok, I tried writing all of this. This is what I got: Reading package lists... Done [break] Building dependency tree [bk] Reading state information... Done [bk] E: Unable to locate package brother-lpr-drivers [bk] E: Unable to locate package laser1

Comment: what is your ubuntu version? can you include the full error message in the question?

Comment: That was the full error message I wrote up there, I just put line breaks as [bk]. My version is 14.04, 32-bit (I have 1 gb of RAM).

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and then try.